# php get path info with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

?>
```

Here is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /something
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I input something/index.php/hello, the result whould be /hello
But if I something/hello, it says that 
Undefined index: PATH_INFO in /Library/WebServer/Documents/xcart/index.php on line 3

How can I get the same result?

Comment: Well this behaviour is exactly what that server var was designed for. I suggest you try to explain what you _really_ want to do and why. Maybe then we understand what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/?$ something/$1
</IfModule>
```